# Two way communication in two android emulators

Tags: android

I have a server client code in one file, running fine for the client to server when using 
redir add tcp:clientEmulatorPort:serverEmulatorPort

but for the server side to reply back to client I have redirection issue of the ports as redir add tcp:serverEmulatorPort:clientEmulatorPort because now server emulator has to generate response to client emulator, does anyone have idea how can I perform this second port redirection or any other way of two way communication? everything else is working fine because I have checked that over devices just want to run it over 2 emulators as well.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way communication is not possible. You have to remove the port redirection and then add it again to do communication from the second emulator.